# Pull data into dropdown list from mysql but not refreshing upon selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to pull data from a MySQL database into a drop-down list which I have successfully done. But the problem is that when the data is loaded and I make a selection, then a table should be displayed based on the selection made. It works but when the table is displayed the selected item doesn't stay selected in the drop-down list- it refreshes the page and the drop-down list return to the default selected value.

```
<form method="post">

<label style="padding-left:13%;">Select Course: </label>
      <?php
      $query=mysqli_query($dbc,"select * from courses");

      echo "<select class='form-control' name='course_code' style='height:50px; width:300px;'  onchange='this.form.submit()' >";     
       echo "<option value='' selected='selected'>-Select-</option>";
      while($course_code=mysqli_fetch_row($query))
      {       
       ?>

       <option class="sel" value="<?php echo $course_code[0];?>"><?php echo $course_code[1]; ?> </option>;
       <?php

       }

      echo "</select>";?>

      </div> <!--col-lg-4-->
      </form>

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$ccode=(isset($_POST['course_code']) ? $_POST['course_code'] :null);


$_SESSION['ccode']=$ccode;

?>
```

I want to pull data from the MySQL database in the drop-down list, select an item and have it stay selected when the table is displayed based on my selection without having the page refresh and the selected item is gone from the drop-down list.

Comment: use `AJAX` to pull the data from database.

Comment: can you paste the code where the form is post to.

Comment: can you give me a sample code of how to do it using ajax. @julekgwa looking at the code its there check the select statement in the echo tag.

Comment: Try using Ajax with an onchange event on your first dropdown

Comment: try this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: @manian sample code please or send me a link.

Comment: In order for an option to be selected on page load you have to give it the "selected" attribute, which currently is hard-coded to be assigned to `<option>-Select-</option>`.  You would have to alter your code to see if an option has been selected, and write the "selected" attribute on that option if so, otherwise write it on the default option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [selected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-selected) boolean attribute of the `<option>` tag when the item has been selected (and remove it from the first option - i.e. the one with empty value). When the code matches the value in the POST data, then include ***`selected`*** in the markup for the given option.

```
while($course_code=mysqli_fetch_row($query))
{  
    $selected = '';
    if ($course_code[0] == $_POST['course_code']) {
         $selected = 'selected';   
    }
    ?>
    <option class="sel" value="<?php echo $course_code[0];?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $course_code[1]; ?> </option>;
```

output (after second option from database query is selected):

```
<select class="form-control" name="course_code" style="height:50px; width:300px;" onchange="this.form.submit()">
     <option>-Select-</option>
     <option class="sel" value="phys">Physics </option>;
     <option class="sel" value="mth" selected>Math </option>;
</select>
```

See it demonstrated in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/41wz-j7ge)

Comment: i am using your code but its just displaying one course from the database. please try it using a database rather than doing an array.

Comment: Hmm - so you want to allow selecting multiple options?

Comment: No not selecting multiple options but i its not pulling all courses from the database in the dropdown list its just pulling one.

Comment: Did you change the SQL query (i.e. `$query=mysqli_query($dbc,"select * from courses");`)?

Comment: its working now thanks. i was using your js fiddler code instead. thats the reason why it wasn't working thanks alot.